# How to numerically sort an array like this: ['11--2017 name.png','1--2016 name.png','2--1999 name.png']

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, operator-precedence

Am I correct that character precedence would order these like this:

`1--2016 name.png, 11--2017 name.png, 2--1999 name.png`

Numerically, however, they would be like this:

`1--2016 name.png, 2--1999 name.png, 11--2017 name.png`

That is, if I'm looking at the first numbers alone. How do you *numerically* sort an array with strings like this? Namely, integers appended with "`--`".

---

It's important to note that these "strings" are actually pathnames which cannot be renamed. See [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for more information.

Comment: Answer edited. Note that your question, even after edit, remain misleading for possible future answers: if your array come from `glob('Images/*.png')` (as per deleted comment), the solutions provided for `1--2016.png` will not work in your real case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit, after modified question:

After your edit, obviously all answers in this thread are wrong. Also, you don't have to only copy-and-paste a piece of code, but to read entire answer. Sure enough, in my original answer, I say:

> if you have a value like “12--3”, it will be sorted like “123”

So, you could see right away that your real case is not coherent with provided sample.

This second solution will sort an array by *number at start of given basename path followed by two dashes.* It will be applicable on following cases:

```
String                          Will be sorted by
------------------------------  -----------------
/Absolute/Path/12--             12
/Absolute/Path/12--2001.png     12
/12--2001.png                   12
12--2001.png                    12
a12--2001.png                   a12--2001.png
-12--2001.png                   -12--2001.png
```

Having this array:

```
[
    '/path/to/image/1--2016 name.png', 
    '/path/to/image/11--2017.png', 
    '/path/to/image/2--1999.png' 
]
```

You can replace regular expression patter of above original solution with this pattern:

```
~^(.*/)?(\d+)--[^/]*$~
```

And above array will be sorted in this way:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /path/to/image/1--2016 name.png
    [1] => /path/to/image/2--1999.png
    [2] => /path/to/image/11--2017.png
)
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/551227)**</kbd>

Pattern explanation:

```
~
 ^          # Start of string
 (.*/)?     # Group 1 (optional): zero-ore-more characters followed by a slash
 (\d+)      # Group 2: one-or-more digits
 --         # two dashes
 [^/]*      # zero-or-more characters, except slash
 $          # End of string
~
```

In the future, take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

---

#### Original answer (for [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36538336/3)):

There are surely many ways to obtain your result. Using `usort` and `preg_replace`:

```
$array = ['11--','23--','1--'];

usort
(
    $array,
    function( $a, $b )
    {
        return preg_replace( '~[^\d]~', '', $a ) - preg_replace( '~[^\d]~', '', $b );
    }
);
```

`$array` now is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1--
    [1] => 11--
    [2] => 23--
)
```

Above solution will sort your array *deleting*<sup>1</sup> all not digits characters.
So, if you have a value like `12--3`, it will be sorted like `123`. Consequently, it doesn't work on not-integer or negative numbers.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, the original array values are not changed.

Comment: It's probably important to note that these "strings" which I speak of are actually pathnames which cannot be renamed.

Comment: No renaming in my answer (as you can see in the result). I say “deleting” improperly (`preg_replace` is inside a function, and values are not passed by reference). `usort` doesn't change array values. You can try and see...

Comment: What I'm saying is this: Using your method would not work because the "strings" I'm dealing with are actually the pathnames for images; _i.e._, `/path/to/image/11--.png`, `/path/to/image/1--.png`, `/path/to/image/2--.png` I'm using [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), which returns an array, and is in fact the array I'm dealing with. Additionally, vis-a-vis my comment on renaming, I wanted you to know that using PHP's [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) is not allowed for my particular application because of permission issues.

Comment: Your method would rename the pathnames, and so the resources would not function properly, you see?

Comment: My method doesn't change anything! You don't understand `usort` behavior. See this [demo](https://eval.in/550789) Your question is 'how to sort': how can you think that the answer contemplate a replacement? sort is sort!

Comment: I have to go. In your question there is an array sample. My method ( and also @Jek method) sort as you request. Also, it sort as your request in comment above (also Jek method do it). If your real strings are different, you have to ask consistently (and your pastebin doesn't provide any useful info)

Comment: I'm trying your code exactly as you instructed, of course I edited the regex, and it has incorrectly sorted my pathnames. My regex is correct; Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a quick fix to getting this done, you could:

```
$strings = array('5--', '2--', '11--');
$newStrings = array();

foreach ($strings as $string) {
  $stringNew = str_replace('--', '', $string);
  array_push($newStrings, $stringNew);
}

sort($newStrings);

$doneArray = array();

foreach ($newStrings as $newString) {
  array_push($doneArray, $newString.'--');
}

// $doneArray is the new array full of the sorted strings.
```

I didn't really bother with the variable names, but that's a nice way to do it.

Comment: Again, the strings I'm dealing with are pathnames. Changing a pathname results in broken links.

Comment: I don't get how that will change the pathname, or any resources or interfere with permissions, but okay :)

Comment: `$images = glob("images/*.png");` That is the array I am dealing with. When I go to call on any element in this array to display an image, your method would make it so that I am calling a file that does not exist because the pathnames are the element being called.

Comment: If you mean that the `.png` is being removed then add that to the end of the concastonation at `$newString.'--'`, and that will add that to the end of it, other than that when you use the `glob` function all it's doing is putting strings into the array.

Comment: I think I just need to make a dictionary based on the isolated numbers important in the image name.

Answer (score 0):

`natsort`

---

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

---

I'm not sure how `glob` sorts things as they come in, but I thought that `sort` would have ordered them correctly, but `natsort` will do the trick.